# Disable GNU screens selection buffer / clipboard management

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

I'm running GNU screen-4.6.1 in a graphical terminal emulator on Gentoo Linux.

Whenever I detach from a session (e.g. Ctrl+a, d) or attach to a session (e.g. screen -r), my current Primary Selection and clipboard buffer appear to get emptied.

I can only presume that screen is trying to do some fancy clipboard handling/persistence across sessions. I cannot find any information on such a functionality in GNU screen. I thought I was going crazy, but it's definitely screen which messes with these buffers.

Whatever it is, I want to disable it, as it messes up my workflow. What is this "feature" called, where can I learn more about it, and how do I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

GNU **`screen`** uses its terminal description to find how to initialize the screen.  In infocmp's output, that would be shown by the settings for **`smcup`** and **`rmcup`**, e.g.,

```
infocmp -1 screen |grep "mcup="
```

produces

```
    rmcup=\E[?1049l,
    smcup=\E[?1049h,
```

for xterm (and most of the terminals which imitate it), that switches to the *alternate screen*.  Normally your *primary selection* "lives" on the terminal's window, and switching to the *alternate screen* clears the window and replaces it by something else.

xterm has a resource setting ([**`keepSelection`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:keepSelection)) which can be set/unset by an entry in the control/middle mouse-menu [*"Keep Selection"*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT-Options:Keep-Selection).  Setting that (for xterm) may preserve the selection; other terminals may either keep the selection "indefinitely", or simply discard it in this case.

The easy fix for this problem (terminal-independent) is to avoid using the alternate-screen with GNU **`screen`**, e.g.,

```
infocmp -1 screen |grep -v "mcup=" >foo
sudo tic foo
```

to replace its terminal description without those capabilities.  Of course this requires you to restart **`screen`**, to use only the *normal screen*.

There is only one *alternate screen*.  If you are running some application within GNU **`screen`**, then switching to/from that application will use screen's ***simulated*** *alternate screen*, which will have a different behavior than running it outside **`screen`**.

Comment: Thanks, this seems plausible. So you're saying that it's really the terminal emulator that clears the buffers when switching to the alternate screen? Shouldn't this also affect tools like `htop`, `mc` or `less`? I've never had these clear the buffers. I currently cannot reproduce the effect even with GNU screen, so there must be some conditions to be met to trigger it. I wonder...